# ext js disable a onmousedown

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to sencha ext js how can I disable the onMouseDown with a click of a button prevent the user from drawing on the canvas

Ext js 6.5.2

This is the View

```
tbar: ['->', {
         text: 'Disable',
         handler: function () {
            // Remove all the sprites and redraw.
            onMouseDown.setDisabled()(!onMouseDown.isDisabled());
            this.setText(action.isDisabled() ? 'Enable' : 'Disable');

  }],
```

This is the Component

```
onMouseDown: function (e) {
            var targetElement = this,
                me = Ext.getCmp(targetElement.id),
                surface = me.getSurface(),
                xy, x, y;

        if (!me.sprite) {
            xy = surface.getEventXY(e);
            x = xy[0];
            y = xy[1];

            me.list = [x, y, x, y];
            me.lastEventX = x;
            me.lastEventY = y;

            me.sprite = surface.add({
                type: 'path',
                path: ['M', me.list[0], me.list[1], 'L', me.list[0] + 1e-1, me.list[1] + 1e-1],
                lineWidth: 20,
                lineCap: 'round',
                lineJoin: 'round',
                draggable: 'true',
                strokeStyle: new Ext.util.Color(0,0,0)
            });
            surface.renderFrame();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to have a condition like this:
_if canvas not to be drawn, e.preventDefault()_

Comment: @kamp okay will try

Comment: @kamp does not work I tried on the tbar: ['->', {  {
         text: 'Disable',
         handler: function () {
            // Remove all the sprites and redraw.
             e.preventDefault()
        }

    }],

Comment: What version of ExtJS is it? To be honest I cant understan what is `onMouseDown` in your example. Within button handler you just use it assuming it is in the scope and within component its overrided private method... Can you update your question, please?

Comment: @SergeyNovikov when I click the button disable I want to disable the user from drawing on the canvas

Comment: Yes, what you want is clear. I cant understand your code. You use `onMouseDown` variable within button handler bu there is no explanation what is it. Assuming it is your canvas all you have to do is `onMouseDown.setDisabled(!onMouseDown.isDisabled());`

Comment: @SergeyNovikov the onmousedown allows the user to draw https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#free-paint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code is based on [free paint example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#free-paint) I think you can do something like this:

```
{
    text: 'Disable',
    handler: function (button) {
        var draw = Ext.getCmp('free-draw');
        if (draw.isDisabled()) {
            draw.enable();
            button.setText('Disable');
        } else {
            draw.disable();
            button.setText('Enable');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bfl) to illustrate.